# _TypeError (type 'MediaFile' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, gallery, picker

I want to store Mediafile in firebase storage but I think there is no method expect for File and Image Is it right ? All I see the firebase storage method is using ref.putFile or ref.putData .That's all for firebase storage method.I am beginner in flutter so there is somethings worng In my question please forgive me.

**Acutally all the code are from gallery_picker package

example,I copy the example and paste them to my project and just modify
then I try to use it and try to put it to firebase storage here is the package which I try **

Here is my full code,

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:facebook_app/models/stories_model.dart';
import 'package:facebook_app/models/user_model.dart' as model;
import 'package:facebook_app/provider/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:facebook_app/screens/home_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:facebook_app/services/image_storage.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gallery_picker/gallery_picker.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import '../provider/user_provider.dart';

// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages

// import '../provider/user_provider.dart' as model;
// import '../provider/user_provider.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        /* light theme settings */
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        /* dark theme settings */
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      home: const MyHomePage(
        title: "Gallery Picker",
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<MediaFile>? medias;
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title, this.medias});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<MediaFile> selectedMedias = [];
  bool _isLoading = false;
  void Storytask(
    String uid,
    String profileUrl,
    String username,
  ) async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      String res = await uploadPost(downloadUrls, uid, username, profileUrl);
      if (res == "success") {
        await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreenLayout()));
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        showSnackBar('Posted', context);
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(e.toString(), context);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.medias != null) {
      selectedMedias = widget.medias!;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  int pageIndex = 0;
  var controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).refreshUser();
    final model.User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreenLayout())),
        ),
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.upload),
            onPressed: () async {
              for (int i = 0; i < selectedMedias.length; i++) {
                String url = await uploadFile(selectedMedias[i] as File);
                downloadUrls.add(url);
                if (i == selectedMedias.length - 1) {
                  Storytask(user?.uid ?? '', user?.photoUrl ?? '',
                      user?.username ?? '');
                }
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Spacer(),
            const Text(
              'These are your selected medias',
            ),
            const Divider(),
            Expanded(
              flex: 5,
              child: Stack(children: [
                if (selectedMedias.isNotEmpty)
                  PageView(
                    controller: controller,
                    children: [
                      for (var media in selectedMedias)
                        Center(
                          child: MediaProvider(
                            media: media,
                          ),
                        )
                    ],
                  ),
                if (selectedMedias.isNotEmpty)
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (pageIndex < selectedMedias.length - 1) {
                            pageIndex++;
                            controller.animateToPage(pageIndex,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.easeIn);
                            setState(() {});
                          }
                        },
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.chevron_right,
                          size: 100,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        )),
                  ),
                if (selectedMedias.isNotEmpty)
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (pageIndex > 0) {
                            pageIndex--;
                            controller.animateToPage(pageIndex,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.easeIn);
                            setState(() {});
                          }
                        },
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.chevron_left,
                          size: 100,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        )),
                  ),
              ]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 65,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < selectedMedias.length; i++)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          pageIndex = i;
                          controller.animateToPage(pageIndex,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              curve: Curves.easeIn);
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            width: 65,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 2,
                                    color: pageIndex == i
                                        ? Colors.red
                                        : Colors.black)),
                            child: ThumbnailMedia(
                              media: selectedMedias[i],
                            )),
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(
              flex: 2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: pickMedia,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<String> downloadUrls = [];
  Future<void> pickMedia() async {
    List<MediaFile>? media = await GalleryPicker.pickMedia(
        context: context,
        initSelectedMedia: selectedMedias,
        extraRecentMedia: selectedMedias,
        startWithRecent: true);
    if (media != null) {
      setState(() {
        selectedMedias += media;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> getGalleryMedia() async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    GalleryMedia? allmedia = await GalleryPicker.collectGallery;
  }
}

Future<String> uploadFile(File file) async {
  final metaData = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg');
  final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
  Reference ref =
      storageRef.child('pictures/${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg');
  final uploadTask = ref.putFile(file, metaData);

  final taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
  String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  return url;
}

uploadPost(List<String> imageUrls, String uid, String username,
    String profileUrl) async {
  String res = "Some Errors occured";

  try {
    String postId = const Uuid().v1();
    Story post = Story(
        postMediaFileUrl: imageUrls,
        profileUrl: profileUrl,
        uid: uid,
        username: username);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('stories')
        .doc(postId)
        .set(post.toJson());
    // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreenLayout()));
    res = "success";
  } catch (e) {
    res = e.toString();
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in `String url = await uploadFile(selectedMedias[i] as File);`

Update the section where you upload media files.

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedMedias.length; i++) {
  String filePath = _selectedDocument.path; // Replace with the correct way to obtain the file path from your MediaFile
  File file = File(filePath); // Convert file path to File
  String url = await uploadFile(file); // Upload the File to Firebase Storage
  downloadUrls.add(url);
  if (i == selectedMedias.length - 1) {
    Storytask(user?.uid ?? '', user?.photoUrl ?? '', user?.username ?? '');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes , I get error there, I try to put your code in my  project but I get this error  "The getter 'path' isn't defined for the type 'MediaFile'.
Try importing the library that defines 'path', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'path'."   @Ashikul Islam Sawan

Comment: gallery_picker package does not have a .path property. So, we've to use 

import 'dart:io';
I've edited my answer... can you try this out?

Comment: I try to put your code but I get error in _selectedDocument the error is "Undefined name '_selectedDocument'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name." @Ashikul Islam Sawan

Comment: My apologies, You should also declare these two var. Also, check more gellary_picker documentation.

File _selectedDocument;  
var path= _selectedDocument.path;